# War directory can't be resolvd

Tags: android, google-app-engine

After migrating from Endpoint V1 to V2, and updating android studio to V3.0 Beta4, it doesn't seem that I'm able to create the "webapp directory" in the build folder for the backend.

Goal:

- being able to deploy the backend.

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Dappengine.useragent=ANDROID_STUDIO -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\Users\user\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg --application=nyanrex --version=1 --oauth2 --oauth2_client_secret=***** --oauth2_client_id=***** --oauth2_refresh_token=***** update D:\AndroidDev\ProjectMars\backend\build\exploded-app
Unable to find the webapp directory D:\AndroidDev\ProjectMars\backend\build\exploded-app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me forever to figure out what was wrong until I seen someone else build. It seems that the compiler looks for the `'WAR_DIR'` inside of `'exploded-backend'` however when building the project it seems that it sets the name inside of `'backend.iml'` from `'exploded-backend'` to `'exploded-app'` for some reason I couldn't figure out. To fix that you just need to look inside of `'backend.iml'` for `'WAR_DIR'` and change the end of the path from `'exploded-app'` to `'exploded-backend'`

From

```
<facet type="app-engine-gradle" name="App Engine Gradle">
  <configuration>
    .
    .
    .
    <option name="WAR_DIR" value="$MODULE_DIR$\build\exploded-app" /> 
    .
    .
    .
</facet>
```

To

```
<facet type="app-engine-gradle" name="App Engine Gradle">
  <configuration>
    .
    .
    .
    <option name="WAR_DIR" value="$MODULE_DIR$\build\exploded-backend" /> 
    .
    .
    .
</facet>
```

Comment: Whoever designed the Android Studio UI should be fired immediately!  This is the most important and basic setting of the AppEngine backend which is almost impossible to find....

Comment: @doctorram ... true, but since Google decided that Android Studio should be only to "design" apps, not back-ends; this is not their problem anymore. However, from what I see in Android Studio, Google is trying to push the developers to Firebase because there is more money for them there than AppEngine or other backends methods.